# use "exit/2" function in erlang shell

Tags: erlang

Three erlang processes have been created in erlang shell and registered locally, named Pid, Pid2, Pid3. Then I want to terminate "Pid" firstly by function "exit/2".

```
(emacs@yus-iMac.local)62> exit(lsaaa_dispatch,test).   ％lsaaa_dispatch is the above Pid's local registered name
** exception error: bad argument
     in function  exit/2
        called as exit(lsaaa_dispatch,test)
```

Why exception happens? 
And why all the three process are terminate?  Because I can't find them in Pman.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

exit/2 accepts a pid, not a term.  And it's defined by the kernel 'erlang' module.

```
exit(whereis(lsaaa_dispatch), test).
```

Of your second question, think of the relationship these processes have with your shell.

Comment: Yes, if the 3 processes are linked to the shell process then when there is an error in the shell they will all die. All errors in the shell cause the shell process to die; a new one is started automatically for you so in many ways you don't notice it. Except for it killing linked processes. N.B. this is not a bug but how it was intended to work.